# How to show specific word/text in output (Windows Forms App/ c#)?

Tags: c#, windows, forms

## Description

This Windows Forms App analyze Error data from a .text file.
The .txt file contain ERROR message from server which is Hundreds or Thousands of lines.

The ERROR Log happen time to time and recover time to time.
So, we have to check the ERROR & ERROR Recover time manually.

Present app Count all the words, but not specific and logical answer

#### Example Errors & Recovery Data in One Seconds

```
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch INFO Slot= 4 rx buf underflow recovery P1 L1 
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch INFO Slot= 3 rx buf underflow recovery P4 L1 
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch INFO Slot= 3 rx buf underflow recovery P3 L1 
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch INFO Slot= 3 rx buf underflow recovery P2 L1 
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch INFO Slot= 3 rx buf underflow recovery P1 L1 
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch ERROR Slot= 1 all alarm status detect  
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch ERROR Slot= 1 led status err detect  
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch ERROR Slot= 1 hitless switching is disabled L2 S4 
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch INFO Slot= 1 line chg from 1 to 2 00000004 S4 
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch INFO Slot= 1 out ASI188 valid present P4 
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch INFO Slot= 1 out signal ASI detect P4 
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch ERROR Slot= 1 no packet detect P4 L1 
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch ERROR Slot= 1 rx buf underflow detect P4 L1 
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch ERROR Slot= 1 hitless switching is disabled L2 S3 
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch INFO Slot= 1 line chg from 1 to 2 00000004 S3 
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch INFO Slot= 1 out ASI188 valid present P3 
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch INFO Slot= 1 out signal ASI detect P3 
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch ERROR Slot= 1 no packet detect P3 L1 
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch ERROR Slot= 1 rx buf underflow detect P3 L1 
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch ERROR Slot= 1 hitless switching is disabled L2 S2 
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch INFO Slot= 1 line chg from 1 to 2 00000004 S2 
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch INFO Slot= 1 out ASI188 valid present P2 
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch INFO Slot= 1 out signal ASI detect P2 
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch ERROR Slot= 1 no packet detect P2 L1 
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch ERROR Slot= 1 rx buf underflow detect P2 L1 
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch ERROR Slot= 1 hitless switching is disabled L2 S1 
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch INFO Slot= 1 out ASI188 valid present P1 
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch INFO Slot= 1 out signal ASI detect P1 
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch ERROR Slot= 1 no packet detect P1 L1 
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch ERROR Slot= 1 rx buf underflow detect P1 L1 
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch ERROR Slot= 4 all alarm status detect  
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch ERROR Slot= 4 led status err detect  
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch INFO Slot= 4 receive packet none detect P4 L1 
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch ERROR Slot= 4 hitless switching is disabled L2 S4 
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch INFO Slot= 4 line chg from 1 to 2 00000004 S4 
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch ERROR Slot= 4 no packet detect P4 L1 
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch ERROR Slot= 4 rx buf underflow detect P4 L1 
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch INFO Slot= 4 receive packet none detect P3 L1 
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch ERROR Slot= 4 hitless switching is disabled L2 S3 
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch INFO Slot= 4 line chg from 1 to 2 00000004 S3 
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch ERROR Slot= 4 no packet detect P3 L1 
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch ERROR Slot= 4 rx buf underflow detect P3 L1 
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch INFO Slot= 4 receive packet none detect P1 L1 
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch ERROR Slot= 4 hitless switching is disabled L2 S1 
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch INFO Slot= 4 line chg from 1 to 2 00000004 S1 
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch ERROR Slot= 4 no packet detect P1 L1 
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch ERROR Slot= 4 rx buf underflow detect P1 L1 
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch ERROR Slot= 3 all alarm status detect  
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch ERROR Slot= 3 led status err detect  
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch INFO Slot= 3 receive packet none detect P4 L1 
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch ERROR Slot= 3 hitless switching is disabled L2 S4 
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch INFO Slot= 3 line chg from 1 to 2 00000004 S4 
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch ERROR Slot= 3 no packet detect P4 L1 
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch ERROR Slot= 3 rx buf underflow detect P4 L1 
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch INFO Slot= 3 receive packet none detect P3 L1 
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch ERROR Slot= 3 hitless switching is disabled L2 S3 
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch INFO Slot= 3 line chg from 1 to 2 00000004 S3 
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch ERROR Slot= 3 no packet detect P3 L1 
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch ERROR Slot= 3 rx buf underflow detect P3 L1 
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch INFO Slot= 3 receive packet none detect P2 L1 
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch ERROR Slot= 3 hitless switching is disabled L2 S2 
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch INFO Slot= 3 line chg from 1 to 2 00000004 S2 
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch ERROR Slot= 3 no packet detect P2 L1 
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch ERROR Slot= 3 rx buf underflow detect P2 L1 
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch INFO Slot= 3 receive packet none detect P1 L1 
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch ERROR Slot= 3 hitless switching is disabled L2 S1 
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch INFO Slot= 3 line chg from 1 to 2 00000004 S1 
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch ERROR Slot= 3 no packet detect P1 L1 
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch ERROR Slot= 3 rx buf underflow detect P1 L1 
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch INFO Slot= 1 receive packet none detect P4 L1 
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch INFO Slot= 1 no signal detect P4 
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch INFO Slot= 1 receive packet none detect P3 L1 
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch INFO Slot= 1 no signal detect P3 
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch INFO Slot= 1 receive packet none detect P2 L1 
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch INFO Slot= 1 no signal detect P2 
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch INFO Slot= 1 receive packet none detect P1 L1 
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch INFO Slot= 1 no signal detect P1
```

Part of ERROR & Recovery:

Look from last line to first line:
"ERROR Slot= 3...P4 L1" >>> "Slot= 3 receive packet...P4 L1"

```
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch INFO Slot= 3 receive packet none detect P4 L1 
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch ERROR Slot= 3 hitless switching is disabled L2 S4 
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch INFO Slot= 3 line chg from 1 to 2 00000004 S4 
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch ERROR Slot= 3 no packet detect P4 L1 
20/05/29 14:03:08 VRX-4Sch ERROR Slot= 3 rx buf underflow detect P4 L1
```

#### This windows app analyze the ERROR data and give specific result.

#### Expected Result:

```
 Name: Signal Problem 
 Port: A Slot3 P4 L1  
Time1: 20/05/29 14:03:08 ~ 20/05/29 14:03:08 (Same Second)  
Time2: 20/05/29 14:03:08 ~ 20/05/29 14:03:08 (Same Second)  
Time3: 20/05/29 14:03:10 ~ 20/05/29 14:03:20 ( 10 Seconds)
```

#### Screenshot Link:

[Error Counter Windows App Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZNob.png)

## CODE

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Log_Error_Counter
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Button_Result_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBoxL.Text = File.ReadAllText("C:\\Users\\ryosh\\Desktop\\Mohammad\\LogAnalysis\\20200529omaezaki-1-log-1.txt");
            string input = textBoxL.Text;
            string myString = textBoxL.Text.Replace("\\r\\n", string.Empty);
            var wordlist = input.Split(null);
            string[] str_Arr = wordlist.ToArray();
            string[] Str_dis = str_Arr.Distinct().ToArray();

            int mycount = 0;

            foreach (var item in Str_dis)
            {
                mycount = (from x1 in str_Arr where x1.ToString() == item select x1).Count();
                textBoxR.Text += item + " : " + mycount + Environment.NewLine;

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please give more detail about what you wnat your program to do. Do you want specifically to find the count of the text  "ERROR" in a specific text file, or do you want to find different texts in different files?
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hello, Thanks. I have explained in detail. Please check.